# How can I iterate over multiple lists in a shell script

Tags: bash

I have two lists

```
A='"foo" "bar"'
foo='"alpha" "beta"'
bar='"gamma" "delta"'
```

I want to iterate over list A and in a nested loop iterate over lists foo and bar so that i can execute a command in the nested loop where i can execute a commands like

```
./submit_to_cluster --x=foo --y=alpha

./submit_to_cluster --x=bar --y=delta
```

Is the iteration over the two lists in a nested manner the best way to do this efficiently?

Comment: What do beta and gamma do?  Have you tried anything?  Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `A` is not a list. If you need a list, use a list. This is a list: `A=(foo bar)`. And this is how to reference an array: `${A[@]}`.

What you are looking for is called indirect referencing. You have the name of a variable in a variable. This is indirect referencing: `${!v}`.

You problem is: how to refer indirectly to an array?

This question has already been answered: [How to iterate over an array using indirect reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180714/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-using-indirect-reference)

This shows how to apply the answer to your example:

```
A=("foo" "bar")
foo=("alpha" "beta")
bar=("gamma" "delta")

for x in "${A[@]}"; do
  xa="${x}[@]"
  for y in "${!xa}"; do
    echo ./submit_to_cluster --x="$x" --y="$y"
  done
done
```

This prints:

```
./submit_to_cluster --x=foo --y=alpha
./submit_to_cluster --x=foo --y=beta
./submit_to_cluster --x=bar --y=gamma
./submit_to_cluster --x=bar --y=delta
```