# unable to stop looping in shellscript using FOR

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

hi guys i have problem in bashscript aws like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in $(aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters eks --query "ResourceTagMappingList[*].{ResourceARN:ResourceARN}" --output text)
do 
for y in $(aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters eks --query "ResourceTagMappingList[*].{Project:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Project:Tags[?Key=='Project']|[0].Value}" --output text)
do
echo "$x"" ""$y"

done
done
```

the output for each aws code if not use FOR is :

value of x if not use for:

```
$aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters eks --query "ResourceTagMappingList[*].{ResourceARN:ResourceARN}" --output text

arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/fetcher    
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/Hotel
```

value Y if not use for:

```
$aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters eks --query "ResourceTagMappingList[*].{Project:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Project:Tags[?Key=='Project']|[0].Value}" --output text

Extra API
Hotel Booking
```

but the output from the shell script is:

```
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/fetcher Extra
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/fetcher API
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/fetcher Hotel
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/fetcher Booking
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/Hotel Extra
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/Hotel API
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/Hotel Hotel
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/Hotel Booking
```

can some one fix this code with the right output like this with spaceline in value y not in new line example:

```
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/fetcher Extra API
arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:id:cluster/Hotel Hotel Booking
```

Comment: See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), which describes the proper way to iterate over line-oriented input in bash.

Comment: Beyond that, if you want _two_ lines of output, not four, you shouldn't be using two nested for loops at all. When you put a `for` loop inside another, you run the inner loop every time the outer loop happens, so you get (number-of-inside-items * number-of-outside-items) output elements. That's not just a bash thing, that's true in every language where `for` has typical semantics.

Comment: [How can I iterate over multiple lists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011069/how-can-i-iterate-over-multiple-lists-in-a-shell-script) is relevant to that.  `paste <(first-aws-command) <(second-aws-command)` is maybe even easier (note that it requires bash, and won't work with `sh`).