# more elegant way to do array using indirect reference in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, indirection

taking the answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180714/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-using-indirect-reference), I would like to see if I can refine my code that is simplified below. Is there someway to merge the function of `myCorrectVar="${myPrefix}_${mySearch^^}[@]"` into the `for i in` line?

```
#!/bin/sh    
myVar_ANIMAL=("fish" "dog" "emu")
myPrefix="myVar"
mySuffix="animal"
mySearch="${mySuffix}"
myCorrectVar="${myPrefix}_${mySearch^^}[@]"
for i in "${!myCorrectVar}"
do
    echo "animal = $i"
done
```

gives output as expected

```
animal = fish
animal = dog
animal = emu
```

Comment: Maybe [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is better place for this kind of questions.

Comment: `/bin/sh` does not know about arrays. Maybe you meant `/bin/bash`?

Comment: If you manage to answer it, add it as your own answer :p. SO encourages to do that.

Comment: @ that other guy, this is not asked as a nested question.  I did not make reference to ${${}} . I was asking if there was another way such as using quotes, ticks or brackets that I am not aware of.