# Get array size with indirect name reference

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting, indirection

I am trying to get the **size of an array**, but I don't know the array name until runtime (it's built dynamically based on a list from a file), so I am trying to use bash indirection with `${!var}`.

This answer comes very close ([How to iterate over an array using indirect reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180714/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-using-indirect-reference)), but falls short of making the array **size** `${#var[@]}` work

*Note:* I am trying to avoid `eval`, and I have Bash >=4.0 but <4.3 (so I cannot use `declare -n`). And I'd rather not iterate over the whole array to calculate size, as it can get very large.

What I have working:

```
# Declare dynamic arrays
for env in INT PROD; do
    declare -A "values$env"
done
# Creates 'valuesINT[]' and valuesPROD[]' arrays

while IFS=$'\n'=, read -r key env val; do
    # Assigns val to index key in dynamic array name values$env
    declare "values$env[$key]=$val"
done <my_file

# Output arrays
for env in INT PROD; do
    valuesArrName="values${env}[@]"
    echo ${!valuesArrName} # this works to output all values
done
```

So I can use indirection with `${!valuesArrName}` to output values

But I cannot use indirection to get array size:

```
valuesArrName="values${env}[@]"
echo ${#!valuesArrName} 
# OUTPUT: ${#!valuesArrName}: bad substitution

valuesArrName="#values${env}[@]"
echo ${!valuesArrName}
# OUTPUT: #valuesINT[@]: bad substitution

valuesArrName="#values${env}"
echo ${!valuesArrName[@]}
# OUTPUT: no error, but always 0
```

Comment: I think `eval` may be the only solution.

Comment: @Barmar if so, what's the "safest" way to use `eval`?

Comment: Couldn't you just increment a counter in the code that fills in the array?