# how can i add to a file from a scalar in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a function that'll accept 2 arguments - the name of a scalar and and a filename and will write the scalar (newline delimited) to that file. I'm getting a "bad substitution" error. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_to_f() {
for y in "${1[@]}"
       do
       echo "$y" >> "$2"
       done
}

mapfile -t arr < <(echo "one" ; echo "two" ; echo "three")

arr_to_f arr file
```

I could do it outside the function using my loop  but ill be using this a lot i think so id rather be able to call it if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "name of an array"? `mapfile` builds an array.

Comment: The immediate issue here is covered in [how to iterate over an array using indirect reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180714/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-using-indirect-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a named reference to your `arr` variable. I also replaced `echo` with `printf` in your code, see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_to_f() {
  local -n myarray=$1
  for y in "${myarray[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$y"
  done >>"$2"
}

mapfile -t arr < <(printf '%s\n' one two three)
arr_to_f arr file
```

You could also get rid of the for-loop in your function:

```
arr_to_f() {
  local -n myarray=$1
  printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}" >>"$2"
}
```

Comment: Generally, this is exactly what I would write myself. One change I would suggest, though, is replacing `>> "$2"` after each individual `printf` with one `>"$2"` after the `done`. That way we're keeping the file handle open through the whole loop rather than re-opening it over and over (thus also reducing filesystem load, as each `close()` updates the inode's mtime, not just the data contents), and also can keep appending new lines without the presumably-unintended side effect of leaving old content still present.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I moved `>>"$2"` after the `done`, I think that was your main point. I kept the redirection as "append" since I don't know if OP wants to overwrite or append.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This answer uses `eval`, and should be avoided where possible. See [Freddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418180/1347519), which uses `declare -n` / `local -n` to create a named reference.

This approach may be necessary if you're using an old version of bash.

---

---

As already pointed out, you're passing the literal string `arr`, and that isn't an array, hence the "*bad substitution*".

You can to use `eval` to build a string that results in expanding to what you're after:

```sh
arr_to_file() {
    local cmd
    printf -v cmd 'local -a _content=( "${%q[@]}" )' "${1}"
    eval "${cmd}"
    printf '%s\n' "${_content[@]}" > "${2}"
}

mapfile -t arr < <(echo "one" ; echo "two" ; echo "three")

arr_to_file arr file
```

`eval` usually gets a big warning notice, so here's yours: "*eval is super dangerous if you don't trust the string you're giving it*".

If we're very careful with `eval`, then it can be used somewhat safely. Here `printf "%q" "${1}"` is used to quote the first argument suitably for shell input (e.g: `printf '%q' '}'` won't break out of the variable's name). Thanks to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for the revised and significantly safer and more readable snippet.

This approach will also work for associative arrays (i.e: arrays that use keys instead of indexes), but the output will be unordered.