# Is it possible to substitute a string inside a variable name?

Tags: bash, substitution

I have three arrays like so:

```sh
bp_hl_test=("HL05" "HL10" "HL15")
bp_lr_test=("LR001" "LR010" "LR100")
bp_mr_test=("MR001" "MR010" "MR100")
```

For sake of example, I want to remove directories where the above arrays are subdirectories:

```
- results
-- bp
--- hl
---- HL05
---- HL10
---- HL15
---- HL20
--- lr
---- LR001
---- LR010
---- LR100
--- mr
---- MR001
---- MR010
---- MR100
```

Some code I'm using is below:

```sh
for i in "${bp_hl_test[@]}"; do
  rm -rf ../results/bp/hl/${i}
done
for i in "${bp_lr_test[@]}"; do
  rm -rf ../results/bp/lr/${i}
done
for i in "${bp_mr_test[@]}"; do
  rm -rf ../results/bp/mr/${i}
done
```

This does what I want, but I wonder if I can shorten this and reuse one bit of code more times.

```sh
bp_test={"hl" "lr" "mr")
bp_hl_test=("HL05" "HL10" "HL15")
bp_lr_test=("LR001" "LR010" "LR100")
bp_mr_test=("MR001" "MR010" "MR100")

for j in "${bp_test[@]}"; do
  for i in "${bp_${j}_test[@]}"; do
    rm -rf ../results/bp/${j}/${i}
  done
done
```

This doesn't work as I cannot, as far as I can tell, substitute inside a variable name like this. Is there a method to do this?

I have looked at the tagged question and it gives me `bad substitution` error:

```sh
for j in "${bp_test[@]}"; do
  for i in "${bp_${!j}_test[@]}"; do
    rm -rf ../results/bp/${j}/${i}
  done
done
```

Comment: It should be `${!bp_${j}_test}`. However, you can't use it for an array variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180714/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-using-indirect-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following with the `-n` option to `declare`:

```
bp_test=("hl" "lr" "mr")
bp_hl_test=("HL05" "HL10" "HL15")
bp_lr_test=("LR001" "LR010" "LR100")
bp_mr_test=("MR001" "MR010" "MR100")

for j in "${bp_test[@]}"; do
    declare -n ary="bp_${j}_test"
    for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
        echo rm -rf -- ../results/bp/"${j}/${i}"
    done
done
```

If it looks good, drop the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack the array in a temporary array.

```
for j in "${bp_test[@]}"; do
   a=( $(set | sed -rn '/^bp_'"${j}"'_test=/ s/[^"]*"([^"]*")/"\1 /gp'| sed 's/)$//') )
   for i in "${a[@]}"; do
       echo rm -rf ../results/bp/${j}/${i}
   done
done
```