# How do I define and the call a function in Bash that loops through an array given as its parameter?

Tags: bash, function, scope

Comments show what errors I get when trying to define a function that loops through an array,

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

local to_be_bckd_p=("lightningd.sqlite3" "emergency.recover")
prefs=("aaa" "bbbb")
 
echo_array() {
  
  #for fl in "${1[@]}"; do echo "${fl}";done #${1[@]}: bad substitution
  #for fl in "${*[@]}"; do echo "${fl}";done #${@[@]}: bad substitution
  #for fl in "${@[@]}"; do echo "${fl}";done #${@[@]}: bad substitution
  for fl in "${to_be_bckd_p[@]}"; do echo "${fl}";done 
}

echo_fn() {
  echo "${1}" 
}

echo_array "${to_be_bckd_p[@]}"
echo_array "${prefs[@]}" #This loops through `"${to_be_bckd_p[@]}"`
echo_fn "Hi"
```

Using the keyword `local` in the function definition does not help.
Why using `${1}` doesn't work in defining a function that is meant to take an array as its argument whereas `${1}` works fine in the definitions of simpler functions such as `echo_fn`?

Comment: Your function is always looping through `${to_be_bckd_p[@]}` not its arguments.

Comment: In the shell, arguments are always *strings*; they cannot be data structures like arrays. What you are doing currently is passing all of the elements of the array as arguments (each element as a separate argument). It's also possible to pass the array's *name* as an argument. But it is not possible to pass an array *as an array*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over an array using indirect reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180714/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-using-indirect-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to pass the values to the function, not the array. The values can be accessed as the elements of the `$@` array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo_array() {
    for fl in "$@" ; do
        echo "$fl"
    done 
}

echo_fn() {
    echo "$1" 
}

to_be_bckd_p=("lightningd.sqlite3" "emergency.recover")
prefs=("aaa" "bbbb")

echo_array "${to_be_bckd_p[@]}"
echo_array "${prefs[@]}"
echo_fn "Hi"
```

Comment: Why using `"$@[@]"` in the function definition doesn't work? I was using `[@]` both in the function definition as well as in the function call, following what I read in  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

Comment: `$@` is a special array, its members are `$1`, `$2`, etc. You can't use the `[...]` syntax for it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `bash 4.2+`, we can use a nameref to provide control of the array (eg, accessing array indices):

```
echo_array() {
  declare -n _arr="$1"                      # nameref

  for ndx in "${!_arr[@]}"                  # loop through array's indices
  do
      echo "$ndx : ${_arr[$ndx]}"           # print 'index : value'
  done
}
```

**NOTE:** `for val in "${_arr[@]}"` will loop through the array's *values*

Take for a test drive:

```
$ echo_array to_be_bckd_p                   # pass the name of the array
0 : lightningd.sqlite3
1 : emergency.recover

$ echo_array prefs                          # pass the name of the array
0 : aaa
1 : bbbb

$ declare -A assoc=( [a]=1 [b]=2 [c]=3 )    # add an associative array to the mix

$ echo_array assoc                          # pass the name of the array
a : 1
b : 2
c : 3
```