# How can i make a bash function that generates every possible filename out of an arbitrary number of arrays?

Tags: bash

I want to automatize a process where I decide some set of parameters and then filenames are generated automatically.
Say I have.

```
param_1=(coke icetea)
param_2=(nugget pizza burger)
param_3=(cheesecake)
.
.
.
```

I want something that takes in these `PARAM` arrays and then outputs:

```
coke_nugget_cheesecake
coke_pizza_cheesecake
coke_burger_cheesecake
icetea_nugget_cheesecake
icetea_pizza_cheesecake
icetea_burger_cheesecake
```

By now i have set up a function that does a recursion, so that a generic number of arrays is accepted:

```
function recursion(){
# check whether there still are arguments
 if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
        then
                local localarr
                for i in $(seq $1) #as bash can't accept more than one array
                do                 # the first input is the lenght of next array
                        shift
                        localarr+=($1) #add the elements to a local array
                done

                # this is where the rest of the
                # magic goes

                shift
                recursion $*
        fi
}
```

Does it make sense to do this in bash or is it just better to move it to python? As you can tell I'm still quite nooby to bash (not that I'm better at python either)

Comment: Do you control the input file format?

Comment: Can't you just do `echo {coke,icetea}_{nugget,pizza,burger}_cheesecake`?

Comment: Python has `itertools.product` which will trivialize most of the work here, it's probably better to switch unless you are interested in bash as a learning exercise.

Comment: e.g. `import itertools ; for x in itertools.product(['coke', 'icetea'], ['nugget', 'pizza', 'burger'], ['cheesecake']): print('_'.join(x))`

Comment: To answer KamilCuk yes, I may change the input format.
To answer @oguzismail I don't think that works when you use variables instead of constant arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to python is overall easier as `itertools` has this capability built into it:

```
import itertools 
for x in itertools.product(['coke', 'icetea'], ['nugget', 'pizza', 'burger'], ['cheesecake']): 
  print('_'.join(x))
```

If you're set on doing it in bash, it might be easier to bite the bullet and write something for `eval` instead of digging into a recursive solution.

You can tell at a glance that this is quite a bit more complex than the python solution, but `make_cartesian_product` will take a list of array names, turn them into a brace expansion string such as `{coke,icetea}_{nugget,pizza,burger}_cheesecake` then use `eval` to hand that off to bash and let it handle figuring out all the combinations.

```
#!/bin/bash
make_cartesian_product() {
  local temp param
  local -a brace_strings param_array
  local IFS=,
  for param ; do
    param="${param}"'[@]'
    param_array=( "${!param}" )
    if (( "${#param_array[@]}" > 1 )) ; then
      printf -v temp '%s' '{' "${param_array[*]}" '}'
    else
      temp="${param_array[0]}"
    fi
    brace_strings+=( "$temp" )
  done
  IFS=_
  eval printf "'%s\n'" "${brace_strings[*]}"
}

PARAM1=( coke icetea )
PARAM2=( nugget pizza burger )
PARAM3=( cheesecake )

make_cartesian_product PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `itertools` but it does not seem to solve my problem. I have moved to reading the input from json file, so the params are stored in a dictionary. Now it would be super easy if could just pass to `itertool.product` the dictionary values, but it does not accept a list of entries. :///

Comment: Might be worth a new question if you need help getting the json data into a format that `itertools` approves of, the answer is going to depend on what your json looks like exactly. In the simplest form (keys are parameter names and values are lists of options) it could be as straightforward as `for item in itertools.product(*my_dictionary.values()): print('_'.join(item))`

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean (except for spurious warnings about unused variables) code demonstrates one way to use a recursive function in pure Bash code to generate the filenames:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

params_1=(coke icetea)
params_2=(nugget pizza burger)
params_3=(cheesecake)

function generate_filenames
{
    local -r prefix=$1

    if (( $# == 1 )); then
        printf '%s\n' "$prefix"
    else
        local aref="$2[@]" elem
        for elem in "${!aref}"; do
            generate_filenames "${prefix}${prefix:+_}${elem}" "${@:3}"
        done
    fi
}

generate_filenames '' params_1 params_2 params_3
```

- The first argument to the `generate_filenames` function is a prefix string that is printed at the start of every output line.  As the recursion gets deeper the prefix string gets longer.
- See the [answer by Robin A. Meade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25880676/4154375) to [How to iterate over an array using indirect reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11180714/4154375) for an explanation of `aref="$2[@]"` and `"${!aref}"`.
- Like a lot of Bash code that uses indirect variable names, this code can break due to variable name clashes.  In particular, it will break if you pass it an array name of `prefix`, `aref`, or `elem`.
- I replaced the ALL_UPPERCASE array names with lowercase alternatives to avoid the danger of clashes with the large number of special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that are used in shell programming.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).

Answer (score 0):

It is super easy at the shell with Ruby:

```
#!/bin/bash

p_1=( coke icetea )
p_2=( nugget pizza burger )
p_3=( cheesecake )

ruby -e 'inp=ARGV.map{|f| File.open(f).read.strip.split}
puts inp[0].product(*inp[1..]).map{|a| a.join("_")}.join("\n")
' <(echo "${p_1[@]}") <(echo "${p_2[@]}") <(echo "${p_3[@]}")
```

Prints:

```
coke_nugget_cheesecake
coke_pizza_cheesecake
coke_burger_cheesecake
icetea_nugget_cheesecake
icetea_pizza_cheesecake
icetea_burger_cheesecake
```

This will take any number of inputs as arrays and combine them into a cartesian product.

If you want to support spaces in the input, you can use `\n` to delimit input strings:

```
#!/bin/bash

p_1=( coke "ice tea" )
p_2=( nugget pizza burger )
p_3=( cheesecake )

ruby -e 'inp=ARGV.map{|f| File.open(f).read.strip.split(/\R/)}
puts inp[0].product(*inp[1..]).map{|a| "\"#{a.join("_")}\""}.join("\n")
' <(printf "%s\n" "${p_1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${p_2[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${p_3[@]}")
```

Output:

```
"coke_nugget_cheesecake"
"coke_pizza_cheesecake"
"coke_burger_cheesecake"
"ice tea_nugget_cheesecake"
"ice tea_pizza_cheesecake"
"ice tea_burger_cheesecake"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can *almost* be done easily in bash, with [the `declare` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare):

```bash
IFS=,
declare -a "filenames=({${param_1[*]}}_{${param_2[*]}}_{${param_3[*]}})"
declare -p filenames
```

```bash
declare -a filenames=([0]="coke_nugget_{cheesecake}" [1]="coke_pizza_{cheesecake}" [2]="coke_burger_{cheesecake}" [3]="icetea_nugget_{cheesecake}" [4]="icetea_pizza_{cheesecake}" [5]="icetea_burger_{cheesecake}")
```

[Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) only works with strings if there's a comma.

Comment: Brilliant, but only if all the members actually expand, no? `param_3` would need to be `( cheesecake and_something_else )`

Answer (score 0):

If all array variables have a common and unique prefix (like `param_` in this case), you could use the following [parameter expansions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142692/can-i-set-a-pkl-property-value-outside-of-an-object-declaration)

- `${!param_@}` to iterate over all of these arrays, and in extension over their values as well
- `${out[@]/%/_string}` to append a `_` and those values to each item in the output array
- `${out[@]#_}` to remove from each item the initial `_` introduced by the first array processed

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -a param_1=(coke icetea)
declare -a param_2=(nugget pizza burger)
declare -a param_3=(cheesecake)
.
.
.

declare -a out=("")          # one empty string that gets multiplied

for var in "${!param_@}"; do arr="${var}[@]"; readarray -d '' out < <(
  for item in "${!arr}"; do printf '%s\0' "${out[@]/%/_${item}}"; done
)
done

printf '%s\n' "${out[@]#_}"  # print output array
```

```
coke_nugget_cheesecake
icetea_nugget_cheesecake
coke_pizza_cheesecake
icetea_pizza_cheesecake
coke_burger_cheesecake
icetea_burger_cheesecake
```

Comment: This also supports items containing whitespace characters (spaces, newlines, …).

Answer (score 0):

The way to do Cartesian products in Bash is to leverage its brace expansion:

```
$ echo {coke,icetea}-{nugget,pizza,burger}-cheesecake
coke-nugget-cheesecake coke-pizza-cheesecake coke-burger-cheesecake icetea-nugget-cheesecake icetea-pizza-cheesecake icetea-burger-cheesecake
```

The problem is that this expansion is part of the Bash syntax, rather than data. To make a program which inputs arbitrary sets, we have to massage the data into brace expansion notation, and then pass that to `eval`.

A possible start is this:

```
param1='{coke,icetea}'
param2='{nugget,pizza,burger}'
param3=cheesecake

eval echo $param1-$param2-$param3
```