# what is the best way to loop multiple arrays in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to figure out the best way to loop multiple array values together.

Sample arrays:

```
a = (1 2 3 4)
b = ('A' 'B' 'C')
c = ('x' 'y')
```

Now I want to create a combination of commands like following.

```
command A x 1
command A y 1
command A x 2
command A y 2
command A X 3
....
command C x 3
command C y 3
command C x 4
command C y 4
```

Please help. I was trying with the following, but not sure if that works. Please note, I am a beginner in coding/bash, facing similar requirement at work.

```
#!/bin/bash

a = (1 2 3 4)
b = ('A' 'B' 'C')
c = ('x' 'y')

for aa in a; do
    for bb in b; do
        for cc in c; do
            command $(aa[@]) $(bb[@]) $(cc[@])
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: If you try to run this, it will be pretty clear that it does *not* work. spellcheck.net will do a good job of catching the most glaring errors and suggesting how to fix them.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: This looks a lot like [a possible solution to a reduced version of] this mornings [How can i make a bash function that generates every possible filename out of an arbitrary number of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78140909/how-can-i-make-a-bash-function-that-generates-every-possible-filename-out-of-an). The OP here has even put spaces around the `=` just like the poster of that question originally had. Any relationship? Are you trying to create a solution for a fixed set of 3 arrays or any number of arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When you iterate over `a`, `b` and `c` you get one element at a time in `aa`, `bb` and `cc`, so those are the variables you should use, but they are not arrays; they are scalars, so just use `"$aa"`, `"$bb"` and `"$cc"`.
- You need to remove the spaces around `=` in your assignments.
- Use `${a[@]}` etc. in the loops over the elements in the arrays.

Example (with `command` replaced with `echo`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

a=(1 2 3 4)
b=('A' 'B' 'C')
c=('x' 'y')

for aa in "${a[@]}"; do
    for bb in "${b[@]}"; do
        for cc in "${c[@]}"; do
            echo "$aa" "$bb" "$cc"
        done
    done
done
```