# Can I set a pkl property value outside of an object declaration?

Tags: pkl

Is there a syntax for doing this in pkl? The following fails:

```
class Foo {
    Bar: String
}

f = Foo {
    Bar = "Baz"
}

f.Bar = "Something else"

output {
    value = f
}
```

```
–– Pkl Error ––
Mismatched input: `.`. Expected one of: `{`, `=`, `:`

9 | f.Bar = "Something else"
     ^
at fail (file:///Users/ezbeard/Source/pkl/fail.pkl, line 9)
```

I also can't set a property value within a class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I set a pkl property value outside of an object declaration?

All Pkl data is [immutable](https://pkl-lang.org/main/current/introduction/concepts.html#immutability). "Changing" something just yields new data. For objects, [amend](https://pkl-lang.org/main/current/language-reference/index.html#amending-objects) them into a new object to get a copy which "only differs in selected properties":

```
class Foo {
    Bar: String
    Num: Number
}

f: Foo = new {
    Bar = "Baz"
    Num = 42
}

g = (f) {
    Bar = "Something else"
}

output {
    value = g
}
```

```
Bar = "Something else"
Num = 42
```

---

> I also can't set a property value within a class method.

You can set default properties directly within the class:

```
class Foo {
    Bar: String = "Something else"
}

f: Foo

output {
    value = f
}
```

```
Bar = "Something else"
```